# What could be the reason for segmentation fault in python bindings

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault, cython, python-bindings

I want to write python bindings to a c library using cython. The library represents a multithreaded http server and exposes it's API via a header file. Following the cython guide, I wrote a pxd and a pyc file, containing definitions for 3 basic functions:

```
struct server *server_init()
int server_start(struct server *)
int server_stop(struct server *)
```

The python wrappers looks similar to:

```
cdef class Server:
    cdef library.server *_server

    def __cinit__(self):
        self._server = library.server_init()

    def server_start(self):
        return library.server_start(self._server)

    def server_stop(self):
        return library.server_stop(self._server)
```

The bindings work fine, the server starts and serve content, however, when I stop the server from python, most of the time, the python interpreter crashes with a segmentation fault. The crash happens *after* the return from c server_stop, and I have no idea what could cause the segfault.

The memory allocation/initialization/free take place in these 3 functions and are handled entirely by the c library, internally.

Maybe I'm missing something, so what could be the reason of the segmentation fault error?

EDIT:

It doesn't reproduce in valgrind nor gdb. However, I generated a core dump, and the backtrace looks like this:

```
#0  0x00007f4cd0020008 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#1  0x00007f4cd00208b3 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#2  0x00007f4cd0020c54 in _Unwind_ForcedUnwind () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#3  0x00007f4cd5194630 in __GI___pthread_unwind (buf=<optimized out>) at unwind.c:129
#4  0x00007f4cd518c85b in __do_cancel () at ../nptl/pthreadP.h:264
#5  sigcancel_handler (sig=<optimized out>, si=<optimized out>, ctx=<optimized out>) at nptl-init.c:214
#6  sigcancel_handler (sig=<optimized out>, si=<optimized out>, ctx=<optimized out>) at nptl-init.c:173
#7  <signal handler called>
#8  0x00007f4cd4eba72b in accept4 (fd=<optimized out>, addr=..., addr_len=<optimized out>, flags=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/accept4.c:38
#9  0x00007f4cd3a2ee50 in ?? ()
#10 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Have you tried `valgrind`?

Comment: @Veedrac, I couldn't get it reproduced using valgrind nor gdb. I was able to generate a core dump, see edit.

Comment: Apologies, but I don't see enough there to go on. Can you boil this down to a minimal sample that also crashes?

Comment: @Veedrac, I tested on other machine and it doesn't reproduce, so I don't investigate this anymore. It seems to be some weird bug during thread cancelling, which I guess hasn't much to do with cython.